# Handle POST request sent from an external site for login?

Tags: login, authentication, single-sign-on

How do I send a `$_POST` request to my WordPress application from an external website, and handle it here? I want to send user credentials, along with additional login data, to perform an auto-login.

1. Do I need to define a new URL for handling the $_POST request?
2. Which action hook do I need to use for handling such a request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1. Do I need to define a new URL for handling the $_POST request?
```

No, you don't need to define new URL.

```
2. Which action hook do I need to use for handling such a request?
```

You can use `init` hook.

### Sample code

```
function my_theme_send_email() {

    if ( isset( $_POST['email-submission'] ) && '1' == $_POST['email-submission'] ) {

        // Send the email...

    } // end if

} // end my_theme_send_email
add_action( 'init', 'my_theme_send_email' );
```

Now you can call your website with POST required POST parameters.

### Update:

[image: Executed function on init method]

```
Executed function on init method
```

[image: my code]

```
my code
```

Comment: `init` is used when you're handling requests **within** the WordPress site. Not the requests coming from an external source. This is what the Codex says: `Fires after WordPress has finished loading but before any headers are sent.`

Comment: I think you misunderstood it. When you call your website url, WordPress is already initialized. And it will handle request.

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: But then the email address is still a `$_GET` parameter in the same context, right? I need to send the `$_POST` request from an external URL. The website will not necessarily be loaded.

Comment: How does $_GET or $_POST make any difference with WordPress loading? I think you first try your code before arguing.

Comment: I am not arguing! Okay. Let me try what you're saying and get back.

Comment: It doesn't work. If I make a `$_POST` call from a rest client, it doesn't perform an action it should.

Comment: It should work. Dont copy my code, do some changes according to your needs. Post some code in question to get more clear view.